# Receiver doesn´t react on Alarm in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarm

... and i still have no Idea whats wrong. Hopefully someone can help me, i´m not reallyexperienced in Android.

This is my Alarm Service, defined in Reporter.java:

```
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Reporter.MyReceiver.class);
PendingIntent  pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1*1000, 1*30*1000,  pendingAlarmIntent);
```

This is my receiving inner Class:

```
    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public MyReceiver(){
    super();
}

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("log_cat","Alarm empfangen");
    new GetControls();
}
```

}

And this is what i added to the Manifest:

```
         <receiver android:name="de.sonderfarben.tmc_reporter3.Reporter$MyReceiver" android:process=":remote"/>
```

thanx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have specified a time in the past. If you are trying to have your event occur one second from now, with an `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` alarm, use `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+1000`, not `1*1000`.

---

**UPDATE**

Also, you cannot use a regular inner class. You can use a `static` inner class, or a separate public class. Regular inner classes can only be instantiated by an instance of the outer class; Android does not have one of those to use.

Comment: Perhaps that was one mistake.

Comment: i get: 
unable to instantiate receiver [...] no empty constructor. But there is one :-(